# subscribe and unsubscribe a function that contains calls to other functions

Tags: javascript

I have a function that I want to subscribe it to a event queue. When it executes this function I need it to unsubscribe from the queue.

`functionToExecute` is the function I want to execute.

`onDOMReady` subscribes the `attachDOMHandler` function which in turn executes `functionToExecute` and unsubscribes itself. I have:

```
onDOMReady : function(functionToExecute){
        subscribe(this.attachDOMHandler(functionToExecute));
    },
attachDOMHandler : function(functionToExecute) {
        unsubscribe(this.attachDOMHandler(functionToExecute));
        functionToExecute();
    }
```

Everything works fine when I have the following:

```
onDOMReady : function(functionToExecute){
        subscribe(functionToExecute, this, true);
    },
```

However I need the function to unsubscribe after it is executed. My plan was to use the `attachDOMHandler` function which executes the function and has the unsubscribe behaviour.
When I run the former I get a `"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"` in the Chrome console. It looks like it gets stuck in an infinite loop which makes sense since I keep running `attachDOMHandler` in the unsubscribe which gets caught in a loop.
I basically need to subscribe a function that I specify by parameter passing. When the function is executed it unsubscribes. 
Hope I have explained this ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to call the function directly:

```
function f() { // the function to subscribe unsubscribes itself
               // and calls the actual function
  unsubscribe(f);
  functionToExecute();
}

subscribe(f);
```

Comment: functionToExecute(); needs to be parameter passed. functionToExecute = any function

Comment: So f() would be f(aFunction){
  unsubscribe(aFunction);
  aFunction()

}

Comment: @Decrypter: What arguments? Where do the arguments come from?

Comment: I need to pass a function to be subscribed then unsubscribed when it has been executed. The function could b a(), b() or c(). for example the arguments would be f(a) or f(b).

Comment: @Decrypter: If you put this code inside `onDOMReady`, it should just work because a new `f` is created each time.